# writing inductive lemmas in dafny

Tags: z3, dafny

I'd like to prove the following in dafny:

```
function append(xs: seq<int>) : seq<int> {  
  if |xs| == 0 then []  
  else [xs[0]] + append(xs[1..])
}

method test(o:seq<int>, xs: seq<int>, i:int)
requires 0 <= i < |xs|
{  
  if o == append(xs[..i])
  {
    assert o + [xs[i]] == append(xs[..(i+1)]);
  }
}
```

I believe this requires writing an inductive proof using lemmas, but I'm not sure how to write the lemma. The [online doc](https://rise4fun.com/Dafny/tutorialcontent/Lemmas) gave examples using structural induction on the contents of the sequence, but I think in this case I think the induction step needs to be on `i`? I tried writing one as follows:

```
lemma appendLemma (xs:seq<int>, o:seq<int>, i:int)
requires 0 <= i < |xs|
requires o == append(xs[..i])
ensures o + [xs[i]] == append(xs[..(i+1)])
{
  if i == 0
  {
    assert o + [xs[0]] == append(xs[..1]);
  }
  else
  {    
    appendLemma(xs, o, i);
    // what to do here?
  }
}
```

but it keeps asking for a decreases clause, which in this case I'm not sure if there is one?

Comment: What you call `append` seems to be a mere copy of the sequence. Is that what you intended?

Comment: Yes. I'm trying to learn how to write proofs using dafny so I decided to pick something that should be simple enough.

Answer (score 0):

You will do induction on the length of the sequence (both xs and o) and then i will have to decrease as well, as you can see in my proof below. So you could say you do induction on i. But whatever you do, the inner call to appendLemma *has to be on smaller argument(s)*. It represents the Induction Hypothesis, see. That is why Dafny complains about termination.

Since all we know about the function append is its inductive definition, in head/tail fashion, we have to follow that fashion in the proof of the appendLemma and we apply induction on the tail of xs.

I needed an additional lemma (`appendIsCopyLemma`) that catches the observation of Levent Erkok above that append is actually a simple copy. Note that Dafny verifies this lemma without further help, but you have to call it explicitly in the proof of the appendLemma (two times).

Note that the decrease clause, that Dafny missed in the original code, will now be inferred by Dafny by itself; the arguments of the recursive call are of enough help now.

```
// Verified by Dafny 2.2.0
// definition of append and test in the question above
lemma appendIsCopyLemma(xs: seq<int>)
  ensures xs == append(xs);
{ }

lemma appendLemma (xs:seq<int>, o:seq<int>, i:int)
  // decreases i; // Dafny can infer a decrease clause by itself
  requires 0 <= i < |xs|
  requires o == append(xs[..i])
  ensures o + [xs[i]] == append(xs[..(i+1)])
{
  if |xs| == 1 || i == 0
  {
    assert o + [xs[0]] == append(xs[..1]); //redundant
  }
  else
  {
    appendIsCopyLemma(xs[..i]);
    assert o[1..] == xs[1..][..i-1];
    appendLemma(xs[1..], o[1..], i-1);
    appendIsCopyLemma(xs[..i+1]);
    assert xs[..i+1] == append(xs[..i+1]);
  }
}
```